# Cannot edit files owned by 'nobody'?

Tags: user-permissions, nobody

I created a new user named `bob`, and gave it its own /home/ folder on my server so I can SSH into that instead of root.

I had added `bob` into the `nogroup` group as I had read somewhere (or poorly interpreted it) as allowing me to edit `nobody`'s files, but I get permission denied when I try.

How do I edit `nobody`'s files without running *sudo* every time, how do I grant permission for `bob` to edit them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `nobody` and `bob` members of the same group, possibly a new one

`chgrp` the files to the group that they are both members of. `chmod` the files so that the group can read and write them (`chmod g+rw filename`).

`nobody` isn't nobody - it's somebody named "nobody".